# Limits using L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I tutor for AP Calc AB, it's been a couple years since I last took calculus though. My student had a question with a limit using L'Hopital's Rule, with $\infty/\infty$.

The question was: $$\lim _{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{\tan{x}}{3(2x-\pi)^{-1}}$$

This yields $\infty/\infty$, so after taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator: $$\lim _{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{\sec^{2}{x}}{-\frac{6}{(2x-\pi)^2}}$$

Not sure what to do from here. Symbolab gives $-\frac{2}{3}$ as the answer.

Comment: You need to re-apply as long as the form is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/2{}^-} f(x) \times g(x) ~: ~f(x) = \sin(x), ~ g(x) = \frac{2x - \pi}{3\cos(x)}.$

In Real Analysis, you have that if the limit of each of the individual factors exist, then the limit of the product is the product of the limits.

Clearly, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/2{}^-} f(x) = 1.$

Then

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2{}^-} g(x)
= \lim_{x \to \pi/2{}^-} \frac{2x - \pi}{3\cos(x)}. \tag1 $$

From L'Hopital's rule, it is immediate that

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2{}^-} g(x) = -\frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: After simplifying, even without using L' Hospital's rule you can find the limit .

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo Unsure what you are intending.  The $g(x)$ expression results in the $~\displaystyle \frac{0}{0}~$ indeterminate form.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thank you so much.